# I have 2 questions i am not able to solve in applied electromagnetics

Tags: electromagnetism

I will attach the photos of the questions, it was my quarterly test paper
[image]

Consider a continuous line charge distribution along the circumference of a circle of radius 1 unit in the xy plane. With the origin at the center of the circle and using the cylindrical (p. q, z) coordinate system. the charge density y, varies along the circle as y = Ksin^2φ, 0<φ<2pi, K is a constant.

(a)Determine the total Charge in the system

(b) Determine the electric field vector at the centre of the circle

(c) Determine the potential difference between the points A (x=100,y=0,z=0) and B(x=0,y=100,z=0)

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Could you write down just the question you are asking? Also, if you have 2 unrelated questions, it is better to ask them separately.

Comment: @TomášLétal I have added the question in typing above, also are you not able to see the image I uploaded?

Comment: I can see the image, but with blue and red pen marks, from which it seems you got some parts of the questions right but are not sure about the rest.

Comment: Please [edit]  the question to include the attempts that you made to solve each question. That way, we need not waste time replying what you already got right. Please include detailed steps.

Comment: (a) is quite straightforward; right? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @TomášLétal can you help with the second question from the image, don't mind the pen marks, it was done by my teacher while explaining, but I couldn't get him.

Comment: @AJN what about the 1st question part c?

Comment: @SaiGaneshK Have you tried to plot the charge distribution along the circle ? If you plot it, the technique mentioned in the existing answer may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think total charge in the system is just integral around the circle:
$$Q = K\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \sin^2 \varphi d\varphi = K\cdot \left[\frac{\varphi}{2} - \frac{\sin(2\varphi)}{4}\right]_0^{2\pi} = K\cdot \pi$$

If you try to draw how the distribution looks like, it would be something like an eclipse in polar coordinates. So from the center point of view, effects of charges cancel out and electric field vector should be 0.

Similar reasoning works for the last point, where I think the difference is also 0, due to symmetry.